# Why I can't create a package inside another package in Android-Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this:

[image]

I had that package called data, then I tried to create the package 'model' inside data, and it ended up being a single package named 'data.model'

If I try to rename it, this is what happens:
[image]

And If I try to create 'model' inside that one, it says it already exists, and same with 'data' if I try to do it inside the main package.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Packages are hierarchial-  if you put "Model" inside "Data", it will always be "Data.Model".

Now in Android studio-  it optimizes the structure to not show packages that don't have anything in them than other packages.  You can still add classes to Data-  but until you do, the UI will not show it independently to simplify the layout.  It isn't gone, it's just now showing needless complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to choose File -> Repair IDE -> Rescan Project Indexes on showed dialog.